# What other Python Web frameworks provide auto generated admin UI?

Tags: python, django, admin, web-frameworks, web2py

Django's admin is very nice and many of the widgets is reuseable.

What are alternative options? Extensions for other Web frameworks? Auto schema migration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

web2py has something called "admin" which is not equivalent to Django's "admin'. The web2py admin is a fully web based IDE.

web2py also has something called "appadmin" which is similar to Django's admin but not designed to be exposed to users. It is designed for system administrators.

Yet all the widgets in appadmin and more are available to applications. For example {{=crud.search(table)}} will create a search interface, and {{=crud.create(table)}} will create an entry form with validation for records in table. Etc.

Summary:

```
                      Django   web2py
web based IDE         no       yes
database interface    admin    appadmin (*)
crud widgets in apps  some     all      (**)
```

- = Django's is better, web2py's appadmin is for administrators only.
  ** = web2py's are better.

Answer (score 2):

web2py has some builtin admin. You can try it out [here](http://www.web2py.com/demo_admin/default/site)

Answer (score 1):

Others have already mentioned web2py's web-based IDE and database administration. You also asked about schema migration, so I'll point out that web2py does automatic migrations as well. Migrations can easily be turned on or off for all tables or for specific tables. More details in the [book](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/06#Migrations).

Answer (score 1):

The flask framework has flask-admin: http://flask-admin.readthedocs.org/